# Make prediction with PCA function in R

Tags: r, pca

I am using the PCA function from the "FactoMineR" packages to realise a PCA (on scaled data) and I have a problem to predict the correct values for new individuals:

```
library(FactoMineR)
data(iris)
X <- iris[,1:4]
acp <- PCA(X,scale.unit = T)
```

The eigenvectors are in `acp$svd$V`.
The individuals coordinates are in acp$ind$coord.
Normaly, this command line:

```
scale(X,center = T,scale = T) %*% acp$svd$V
```

should give the same values than in `acp$ind$coord` but this isn't the case... I have the same problem using the princomp function ("stats" package).

Can someone explain me why? Thx

Comment: why would centering the matrix given the same result as the loadings of each observation on the dimensions?

Comment: I'am using the matrix multiplication between the source data converted to z-scores (with the scale function) and the eigenvectors. This normaly project the z-scores  data onto the new basis. 

([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) "Project the z-scores of the data onto the new basis")

Comment: (scale(X, center=T, scale =T) %*% acp$svd$V)[150, ] - acp$ind$coord[150, ] <- is only off by a 1000th. The difference probably has something to do with double multiplication and the reporting of significant digits. Seems like what you are doing is right.

Comment: I think I might have found an answer:([link](http://mkseo.pe.kr/stats/?p=9&ckattempt=1)). The guy is multiplicaying the scale result by sqrt(n/(n-1)) (n is the number of individual) maybee to use the unbiased standard deviation estimator  SD(n-1) = sqrt(n/(n-1)) * SDn. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: you can answer your own questions in SO and accept the answer so this question gets marked as answered